# x.abs() vs negation (-x) performance in Rust, when x is a known negative number

Tags: rust, negative-number

Internally which method is more efficient, given that `x` is a known negative number? The resultant positive number is cast to an unsigned type.

```rs
let x = -1;
let y = x.abs() as u32;
let z = -x as u32;
```

Comment: You're probably aware of this, but: It is unlikely that the difference will be noticeable or even measurable in the overall performance of whatever you're building.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Checking these two cases in the [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=release&edition=2021&gist=c42a767c5549ff0d8f0cdff32e20d78c), we get the following assembly:

```
playground::abs:
    movl    %edi, %eax
    negl    %eax
    cmovll  %edi, %eax
    retq

playground::negate:
    movl    %edi, %eax
    negl    %eax
    retq
```

However, if it's known to optimizer that the value of `x` is indeed negative, these two versions became equivalent. For example, these two functions are both semantically no-ops:

```
pub fn extending_abs(x: u8) -> u32 {
    abs(-(x as i32))
}

pub fn extending_negate(x: u8) -> u32 {
    negate(-(x as i32))
}
```

And the assembly for both of them indeed [consists only of the zero-extension](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=release&edition=2021&gist=b8fc148a518bb954810c4c40ff9edeb0):

```
playground::extending_abs:
    movzbl  %dil, %eax
    retq

playground::extending_negate:
    movzbl  %dil, %eax
    retq
```